# Windows Service not updating when code changes

Tags: c#, windows-services

Hi i'm new in Windows Service c#. i followed tutorials and it works perfectly after installation.

Now my problem is when i modify the fonctionnality of the service (modifying c# code), and  i uninstall  & install the windows service, the functionnality remains that of the first installation.

I even restarted the PC and the functionnality  and the functionality has not changed

Is there someone who had this problem?

Comment: Could you give a few more details about the steps you are taking? Have you created an installer? Is your new code change built in debug mode but your installer picks files from release mode? Can you try building the application in release mode and then generate the installer for it? I'm just throwing ideas as I'm not very sure what you've already tried.

Comment: Ok this is my steps:

Comment: Use `sc.exe qc <ServiceName>` and review the `BINARY_PATH_NAME`. Is that really the executable you updated?

Comment: 1- i create a windows service ptroject || 2- In OnStart() service i add some functionnality of   updating database every x seconds  ||  3- on debug mode i add this code:   Service1 ser = new Service1();
            ser.OnDebug();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);

Comment: i t works perfectly   || 4- I add setup project and i configured it after installation the WS works

Comment: after that i modified   the functionnality and reinstall the WS

Comment: and nothing has changed

Comment: Did you check the timestamp of the dll that is there in the service path and the one that you have in the build? If you are creating a installer may be there is some file versioning issue . Please follow how windows installer handles [file replacements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371221(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: i found it. the problem was for versionning of files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had the same problem.If you are using visual studio installer, just delete the .msi and setup.exe from ***"XXX\Release"*** folder and rebuild visual studio installer project. It will recreate both files with updated code changes.

Comment: Hi my release folder dont have the .msi and setup.exe and I have also stopped my service and rebuild my project but my exe file not being updated.

Answer (score 0):

Right click solution > rebuild.  Then run your service again.

Comment: I am doing this but its not working. After rebuild, me exe file is not being updated.

Answer (score 0):

In order run the updated service in Windows which is created in c# follow below steps

1. First of all stop that service in windows service manager (services.msc)
2. Then go to build menu in Visual Studio and click on Rebuild Solution
3. Then go to services and start the service again.

In this way the updated service will run if it is build successfully and the service is created accurately otherwise you will get Service Failure alert in Windows with specific error code.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the solution I tried is different from the marked answer.

Right click the setup project (you get a popup window). Click `Configuration Manager` button at top right, from `Active solution configuration` dropdown, check whether the selected value is `Release`. If it is `Release` then Release folder is updated on building the project; else `Debug` folder.

Hope this will help a few having such an issue.